# Please wait while Windows configures Node.js - slow uninstall

Tags: node.js

I am new to this environment and working through the set up for Phoenix Framework.

I installed Node on Windows before someone recommended switching to LINUX. I need to uninstall it on Windows, but following the typical uninstall process produces:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huham.png)

Microsoft assistant said to leave it (expected to take 5 hours - it has now been over 24).

Comment: The uninstaller is stuck. It happens. Create a restore point.  Cancel the uninstaller. Or, if that doesn't work, bounce the box (reboot).